# How to efficiently define a variable for an ordered pair?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So, I would like to know how to efficiently define a variable (of ordered pair), so I can populate the plane with a particular polygon at certain positions. In particular, I started using this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {0} {
\foreach \x in {0,4,11} {    
\draw (\x,\y) -- (\x +1,\y) -- (\x +1,\y +0.5) -- (\x +0.5,\y +0.5) -- (\x +0.5,\y +1) -- (\x,\y +1) -- (\x,\y);}} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But then, I realized, that I have to change `\y` as well for certain values of `\x`. Instead, I prefer to have with something like

> for (`\x`,`\y`) in {(a,b), (c,d), etc.}

where I can freely define a,b,c,d... and follow this with `\draw`. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I think I got it. So the solution was rather simple (after doing further searching). This seems to work for me:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/0, 4/0, 11/1} {    
\draw (\x,\y) -- (\x +1,\y) -- (\x +1,\y +0.5) -- (\x +0.5,\y +0.5) -- (\x +0.5,\y +1) -- (\x,\y +1) -- (\x,\y);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. You can also use a slight shortcut via relative coordinates `\draw (\x,\y) -- +(+1,0) -- +(+1,+0.5) -- +(0.5,0.5) -- +(0.5,1) -- +(0,1) -- cycle;`. Notice the extra `+` before each coordinate.

Comment: @percusse Thank you for this improvement! This is really what I need. I am really new to Tikz, and comments like this one are really helpful! Thanks pal! =)

Comment: My pleasure. Then here is another one `\draw (\x,\y) -| +(+1,+0.5) -| +(0.5,1) -| +(0,0) -- cycle;` :)